# Jquery clone not passing dropdown selected value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, clone

I have a form with a lot of fields (input text and dropdown) and I want to clone some fields onto other fields. The fields are a combination of database-populated and on-the-fly populated.

The jquery clone() works fine for cloning what was pre-populated at page load but not at all for any on-the-fly user input. I have found a solution for my  fields:

```
$('div.myStuffToCopy').find('input:text').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});

newDiv = $('div.myStuffToCopy').clone(true);
```

With "myStuffToCopy" representing here what the div that contains what I want to copy.

After a lot of research on the dropdown issue, I can't find a solution that works. The fix at https://github.com/spencertipping/jquery.fix.clone, which seems to be the accepted answer, doesn't make any difference (since my dropdown were cloned correctly when they were prepopulated at page load). Is there a way to do the same trick as with the input fields?

EDIT: here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QjDGJ/) to see what I want to achieve: if you modify the first line of fields and click the "copy" link, you'll see that the 2 inputs are copied (thanks to the few JS lines at the top) but not the dropdown.

EDIT2: I have found a way to make it work now ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/QjDGJ/1/)) but the weird thing is that the dropdown clone has the correct value selected but it doesn't show on the screen (on chrome and firefox) - only when submitting the form does the POST value show it's correct. How can I force the dropdown to show the real value?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$(this).attr('value', $(this).val());` ? Which trick? Adding `value` property as an attribute to the cloned element? Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: This ensures the text field values that have been modified post-load are also cloned. Otherwise anything you enter in a text field will not be cloned. I found it on another stackoverflow answer and as the original person puts it: this will change the actual 'value' attribute in the DOM tree, otherwise the data you enter 'on-the-fly' only exists in the DOM 'state'

Comment: To be clearer: without that part, if the user enters "answer" in a text input, you have this: <input name="myinput"> with the value only in the DOM state. By adding these few line it forces it to become <input name="myinput" value="answer"> and therefore the value is now cloned as well (otherwise it wouldn't). That's what I want to do for the dropdown: the user selects something and currently it's not in the DOM tree so it's not cloned. I'm gonna add a demo on jsfiddle shortly.

Comment: jsfiddle added: http://jsfiddle.net/QjDGJ/